# Free dynamically allocate struct in C by typecasting

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I have a struct that is defined as

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char* name;
    float percentage;
}student_t;
```

And in a given function

```
void student_tDeleter(void* val_ref) {
    
}
```

I understand that if a function had to take in void* ptr as its parameter, I have to do type cast in order to access to its memeber variables, but the following code won't work for some reason

```
void student_tDeleter(void* val_ref) {
    free((student_t*)val_ref->id);
    free((student_t*)val_ref->name);
    free((student_t*)val_ref->percentage);
    free(val_ref)
    val_ref = NULL;
}
```

Compiler says that ```warning: dereferencing void* pointer
error: request for memeber "id/name/percentage" in something not a struct or union

I thought its the parentheses. So I added two extra parentheses

```
void student_tDeleter(void* val_ref) {
    free(((student_t*)val_ref)->id);
    free(((student_t*)val_ref)->name);
    free(((student_t*)val_ref)->percentage);
    val_ref = NULL;
}
```

But compiler says that

```
  free(((student_t*)val_ref)->id);
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘free’
  free(((student_t*)val_ref)->percentage);
 note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘float’
 extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
```

How do I properly free() struct memebers?
Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: How did you malloc this struct? You can't free struct members seperately.

Comment: Since it won't compile, how I allocate doesn't matter to this case.

Comment: Be cautious with the `char*` in your structure as you may need to `free` this if you have created a memory block on the fly to store the string that it points to.

Comment: `Since it won't compile, how I allocate doesn't matter to this case.` It does. You only free what you malloc. Since you very likely not malloc'ed all these members one by one, you're not supposed to free them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)**

`->` beats *cast*.

```
(student_t*)val_ref->id
// is like
(student_t*)(val_ref->id)
```

Instead use

```
((student_t*)val_ref)->id
```

**Free pointers**

[@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69574446/2410359) nicely points out code should not attempt to "free" a `float` nor `int`.

---

Repaired code

As `free(NULL)` is OK, let us also allow `student_tDeleter(NULL)`.

```
void student_tDeleter(void* val_ref) {
  if (val_ref) {
    free(((student_t*)val_ref)->name);
    free(val_ref)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and just a quick question. Although ```struct``` is dynamically allocated, but its memebers those are not pointers will die at the end of program automatically without free()?

Comment: @AlexHu Yes.  All 3 members "die" with `free(val_ref)`.  The `free(((student_t*)val_ref)->name)` is not the "death" of the `.name` member, it is the "death" of the data that member points to.  The other 2 members do not have pointed-to data.

Answer (score 1):

The data members `id` and `percentage` are not pointers.

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char* name;
    float percentage
}student_t;
```

So it does not make a sense to apply the function `free` to objects of the type `int` and `float`.

If the data member `name` points to a dynamically allocated memory then you need to write

```
free( ( ( student_t * )val_ref )->name );
```

and then

```
free(val_ref)
```

Pay attention to that casting is an unary operator while the operator `->` is a postfix operator that has higher precedence than unary operators.

Comment: If one has to refer to a void pointer as a `student_t` pointer more than once, it's probably cleaner to do something like: `student_t *s = (student_t *)val_ref; free(s->name); free(s);` than to try to inline the cast and deref.

Answer (score 1):

Non-dynamically allocated members of your struct will be handled by `free`ing the struct. You only need to separately free any dynamically allocated struct members.

For example:

```c
typedef struct a {
    int b;
    char *c;
} a_t;

a_t * create_a() {
    a_t *new_a = malloc(sizeof(a_t));

    new_a->b = 42;
    new_a->c = malloc(new_a->b);

    return new_a;
}

void delete_a(void *d) {
    a_t *a = (a_t *)d;

    free(a->c);
    free(a);
}
```